# How to make mit app inventor so that blocks 1 and 2 behave as in the picture after turning the phone over

Tags: app-inventor

I use google translate
How to make mit app inventor so that blocks 1 and 2 behave as in the picture after turning the phone over

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVeOo.png)

[image: Example]

Does anyone know how to make the blocks behave as in the picture after turning the phone?

Comment: Off the top of my head, two possibles: 1. Have duplicate Block 1 and Block 2, one set in a vertical arrangement, the other in a horizontal arrangement, change their visibility depending on device orientation. 2. Use a dynamic components extension to build the display each time the device is rotated.

Comment: 3. There are also a couple of extensions that will allow you to rotate components, this might be the best approach ?